# Algorithm to validate 1 of N inputs is part of output hash

Tags: hash, mac, hash-signature

Is there an algorithm that allows proofing that an input `x1` was used as 1 out of N inputs to create an output hash `y`, without knowing the other inputs?

I.e. if there are 5 users providing an input hash for example, can we create an output hash that allows each individual user to verify his input was part of the inputs without him needing to know all other inputs?

(it's ok to learn all inputs during the validation process, inputs are not secret just not feasibly available)

Some more info on the concrete usecase:

1. I need to represent the state of a system in a concise way (hash?).
2. The state changes/evolves constantly based on new user inputs.
3. There needs to be a way to check if a specific user input is already reflected in the current state.

The blunt approach would be to represent the system state as the list of inputs but this doesn't work due to some limitations.
Therefore I was hoping there might be a cryptographic function that would allow the state to be represented in a concise way. I've been looking into merkle trees, multi signature schemes etc. but so far haven't found something that really fits the bill.

Comment: It sounds like you could solve your problem with a Merkle Tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree

Comment: @bmm6o unfortunately not, that also requires knowledge of other inputs or their aggregate hash, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Right, the tree would need to be available to anyone who wanted to verify the computation.

Comment: So, what you want to prove is that for a given value $y$ there exists some $x_i$ from a set of size $N$ of values $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\}$ such that $y=H(x_i)$ and that you know said $x_i$ (potentially without revealing it?)? Is interaction allowed in such a proof or is it required to be a statement comparable to a hash value?

Comment: @SEJPM I added more information on my concrete usecase to make it more clear. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @TommyF: Have you tested this idea by the Pigeonhole Principle?  That is, if each of *N* inputs has length of *k* bits and the hash output has length `x` bits, then if `x > N*k` the same output can be produced by many different inputs (2**(x - N*k)) and therefore even if you have a complete input and reproduce the hash calculation arriving at the same output, you can never know if you have the original input or merely a collision.